# Выравнивание формы поиска в шапке WordPress сайта

Tags: html, css, wordpress, вёрстка

Есть сайт по шаблону TwentyTwenty-child

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Отредактировал файл стилей `C:\OSPanel\domains\digitalelectronics.ru\wp-content\themes\twentytwenty-child\style.css` (поменял значения margin-ов по сравнению с файлом `C:\OSPanel\domains\digitalelectronics.ru\wp-content\themes\twentytwenty\style.css`)

```css
/*
 Theme Name: Twenty Twenty Child
 Theme URL: #
 Description: Twenty Twenty Child Theme
 Author: John Doe
 Author URL:
 Template: twentytwenty
 Version: 1.1
 Text Domain: twentytwenty-child
 */
 
 
 .search-form {
    align-items: stretch;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    margin: 0 0 -0.3rem -0.3rem;
 }
 
 @media (min-width: 1000px)
.header-titles .site-title, .header-titles .site-logo, .header-titles .site-description {
    margin: 1rem 0 0 1.8rem;
}

.search-form .search-field, .search-form .search-submit {
    margin: 0 0 0.4rem 0.4rem;
}
```

чтобы придвинуть форму поиска (Найти, Искать) к заголовку - DigitalElectronics, Мир Техники, но не получилось - внешний вид сайта не изменился.

Comment: добавьте display:flex align-items: center для обёртки всех полей поиска и для всей шапки + лучше показать разметку html

Comment: После изменения стилей - CTRL+F5. А по правильности кода что-то сказать сложно не видя пациента.